# Why, in a negative feedback amplifier, do the op-amp input terminals become virtually connected?

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative-feedback, virtual-ground

The equation from the model of the functionality of the op-amp is that

$$V_{out}=A_{0}(V^{+}-V^{-})$$

In case of negative feedback, \$V^{+}=V^{-}\$.

Why do the two terminals in case of negative feedback become virtually connected?

Comment: No - not "virtually connected". That is not the correct conclusion. When two nodes have (nearly) the same potential to ground (voltage), they must not considered as "connected". In this case would a voltage source at the non-inv. input drive a current through the feedback path, which is not true.

Comment: @LvW, But if we connect an ohmmeter between the two nodes (inputs), it will read 0 Ω as if they are connected by a piece of wire...

Comment: No, they won't.  In a normal non-inv amp circuit, the inverting input is driven to a voltage that by definition is *not* perfectly equal to the non-inv input.  Example - if the opamp open loop gain is 1 million, and the output is 1 V above the non-inverting input voltage, then the two inputs are 1 uV apart.  Of course, input offset voltage messes up everything.

Comment: A good explanation is already provided here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181902/positive-feedback-and-virtual-short-in-operational-amplifiers

Answer (score 2):

There are a few good answers here, so I'll just give you an example of negative feedback at work. When driving a car, you know two things: the direction you *want* to go, and the direction you are *actually* going, right now.

If you are steering towards where you want to go, the difference between your desired direction and you actual direction *reduces*. That difference is called the *error*. You always adjust your steering in a manner that reduces the error, otherwise you crash.

The steering instructions you give the car are always in a direction *opposing* the error, giving rise to the term "negative feedback"; if you are steering too sharply, you reduce your steering input, and when your car is not turning fast enough, you increase the steering input. When there's no error, you are turning at exactly the rate required to negotiate a bend in the road, you maintain the current steering wheel position.

Interestingly, you don't need to know how many degrees to turn the steering wheel to cause the car to change direction at some specific rate of degrees-per-second, you simply use negative feedback to adjust steering until your rate of turn is exactly what you want. In other words, negative feedback causes the system to always approach *zero error*.

You can see this with speed control, too. If you are driving too fast, you lift your foot off the accelerator pedal slightly, allowing the car to slow down, and if you are going too slow, you press the accelerator a little harder, to speed up. You always end up travelling at exactly the speed you desire. That's negative feedback at work. The result is always that actual state equals desired state.

Remember, "error" is the difference between the *desired* state of the system, and its *actual* state. Think of the two op-amp inputs as signals representing these two conditions. The actual output state is measured at the inverting input (by feedback from the output), and the desired state is presented to the non-inverting input.

If the actual output potential is too high, the condition present at the op-amp's inputs is \$V_{INV} > V_{NONINV}\$, which causes the op-amp output to *fall* in potential. As it falls, the error (the difference \$V_{NONINV} -V_{INV}\$) reduces towards zero, until eventually the two signals become equal. Ideally, at that point, the output settles where it is. If the output is too low (or it overshoots), then the error changes sign, \$V_{INV} < V_{NONINV}\$. Then the op-amp output begins to rise instead, until it reaches that place where the two inputs become equal.

All this happens incredibly fast, and in this way, the op-amp output always settles at the point where the two inputs are equal, in the same way that you somehow always obtain a steering wheel position that causes your car to turn at exactly the rate you want it to turn, and an accelerator pedal position that corresponds to some constant desired speed.

That's how negative feedback causes actual state to equal desired state, or in the case of an op-amp, \$V_{INV} = V_{NONINV}\$.

Technically, the two inputs are never physically connected, but they do have (almost) exactly the same potential, *as if* they were joined. That's why it's called "virtual".

One of the op-amp inputs must receive information about the desired state, while the other must measure actual state, for this behaviour to occur. The eventual equality \$V_{INV} = V_{NON-INV}\$ is a by-product of that behaviour, not a result of some physical join. By physically connecting them, you are cross-contaminating those two pieces of information. What should be accurate information about desired state, is now influenced by actual state, and vice versa, and the behaviour I just described is lost.

Comment: "In other words, negative feedback causes the system to always approach zero error.". Only if there is an integrator in the compensator whch is the driver making continuous corrections. For a proportional only control system the error approaches the actual direction divided by the open loop gain. The analogy of this answer implies external compensating circuitry which is not implied by the question. Furthermore, the oscillation around steady state will occur only for 2nd order and greater.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the internal workings of the opamp.

The opamp will drive the output based on the difference between the inputs.

Assuming you have negative feedback, this will bring the output to whatever it needs to be to equalize those inputs.  Once the inputs are the same, the output stays at that level.

Simple way to look at it:  The output of the opamp drives the inverting terminal until its voltage matches the non-inverting terminal's voltage.

Comment: but the reason I know is that $$V_{out}/A_{0}=V^{+}-V^{-}$$ and due to that $$A_{0}=\infty$$ the difference between the terminals is equal to zero 

,,is that right ?

Comment: In an "ideal" opamp, yes.  Real world they have finite gain and have to work with the available voltage at their rails.

Comment: @Mans Yes, in an ideal op amp where A₀ is infinite, the difference between the terminals is zero. In a real op amp, A₀ is not infinite, but it's high enough that the difference between the terminals is still *basically* zero.

Comment: @Mans that is a common mistake. You cannot explain virtual ground like that. You can see a counter example in positive feedback.

Comment: The op-amp doesn't "assume" anything. The internal operation of the op-amp gives you \$V_{out}=A(V_+-V_-)\$ (for a small enough input), whether there is negative feedback or not.

Comment: @ThePhoton You are semantically correct.  I will re-word that part to be more precise.  See if you like that wording better.

Comment: @ThePhoton

can you explain why the terminals of the ideal op-amp in case of negative feedback are virtually connected  ? is it due to the math I've written or another reason ?

Comment: They are not really connected.  The output is driving the inverting terminal (via the negative feedback connection external to the opamp) until it matches the other one, making it seem like they are connected.

Comment: @evildemonic 
are you saying that the mathematical approach of trying to prove that the terminals have the same voltage is not correct ?
I mean by dividing the output volt over the infinite gain

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at.  You are using correct equations to describe an ideal opamp with negative feedback.  I'm describing how that relates to the real world.

Comment: @ThePhoton While "the op amp assumes" is a wording that I find a bit objectionable as well, I think it *is* valid to say that the op amp's designer designed it under the assumption that it will be used with negative feedback.

Comment: @evildemonic,
there are users that said the mathematical equation that i've written not the reason that the terminals have the same value in negative feedback which made me doubt my mathematical approach of proving that they have the same voltage

Comment: Well the equation doesn't itself make anything happen.  The equation is used as a model to understand the way a real circuit operates in a simple way.  Your equation is correct, but it assumes infinite gain and voltage levels.  As long as you are within achievable voltage levels and understand the gain is "very large" and not infinite, your equation works just fine.

Comment: I would love to know why my answer is the only one with a down-vote...

Comment: @evildemonic I downvoted because it is the feedback that drives the two input terminals to the same voltage, not "the internal workings of the opamp". The feedback network is external to the opamp, not internal.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simple buffer circuit using an op-amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWB7v9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, \$V_- = V_o\$ and \$V_+ = V_\text{in}\$. Below is the block diagram of a simple buffer. A similar diagram can be derived for other op-amp configurations such as inverting/non-inverting amplifiers:

[image]

It follows from the diagram that
$$\begin{align*} V_o &= eA_0 \\ \\
V_o&=(V_\text{in}-V_o)A_0 \\ \\
V_o + A_0V_o &= V_\text{in}A_0 \\ \\
V_o \frac{1+A_0}{A_0} &= V_\text{in} \\
 \end{align*} $$
Notice that \$\frac{1+A_0}{A_0} \to 1 \ \text{for} \ A_0 \to \infty \$. This implies that

$$V_o = V_\text{in} $$

So it's due to the high open loop gain \$A_0\$ that the voltages at the input terminals become the same.

Comment: Your circuit is a buffer, not an inverter.

Comment: @ThePhoton You are right. I will ammend!

Answer (score 1):

The opamp terminals do *not*, I repeat *not* become "virtually" connected since no current flows between them in normal operating conditions (some opamps have clamp diodes or transdiodes between their inputs and those can conduct when the inputs diverge too much: such opamps are not good to use as comparators).

The expectation for an opamp used in a proper manner (with negative feedback) is that the output will drive the inputs to match essentially immediately.  Underlying that assumption is that \$A_0\$, the open loop magnification, is effectively infinite.  With \$V_{out}\$ being finite, this makes \$V_+-V_-\$ zero.  The assumption is, of course, that a finite \$V_{out}\$ confined to the opamps operating parameters is able to drive that difference to zero.

Comment: so that due to $$V_{out}$$ is being finite and the $$A_{0}=\infty$$  then

$$V_{out}/A_{0}=V^{+}-V^{-}$$
BY dividing  a finite value over infinite value the result becomes zero 
so that what makes $$V^{+}-V^{-}$$ equal to zero ?

Comment: @Mans You can use in-line TeX here by using `\$(math goes here)\$`. The backslashes are necessary.

Comment: It's not what _makes_ \$V_+-V_-\$ zero: the behavior of the output does that.  It's just that there is no other stable solution to where the difference is driven.  Of course, positive feedback has the same solution but it's not stable: any deviation is immediately acerbated. Stability is not a given even with negative feedback: oscillations can be a real problem not apparent in the ideal opamp equations.

Answer (score 1):

> that the two terminals in case of negative feedback become virtually connected?

No. Thinking about it that way will lead you into trouble.

When an op-amp is connected with a feedback network, it tries to drive both its input terminals to the same voltage, but this doesn't happen instantaneously.

Any amplifier will have a bandwidth. If we apply a sudden step to one input, it will change the voltage of the input. Some time later, us, ns or even ps depending on the op-amp speed, a correction signal will come back through the feedback network, to attempt to bring the inputs back to the same voltage.

It's because of this behaviour that there's a very useful 'trick' with virtual ground buffers that are subject to step or impulsive inputs, such as the first amplifier in sigma-delta converter loop. Use a small capacitor from the inverting input to ground. This absorbs the step, turning it into a slower ramp, that the op-amp's speed can deal with without internal nodes being overloaded by the transient large difference in input voltages. For small, slow, signals, this capacitor is in parallel with the zero input impedance of the fed-back op-amp, and so it has no effect on the DC and low frequency behaviour.

Comment: Can you explain what is the reason for an op-amp in negative feedback to make the the terminals have the same voltage? And how does this happen ?

Comment: @Mans An op-amp has two input terminals, inverting, and non-inverting. If the output is connected back to the non-inverting input, then the amplifier will quickly ramp to one rail or the other. While useful behaviour for comparators, it's not very interesting for amplifiers. For amplifiers, we connect a feedback network back to the inverting input. The amplifier drives the output to gain*(V_noninv - V_inv). Gain is ideally infinite, usually 10^5 or 10^6 or so. Therefore the only way to get a finite output voltage is for the difference in input voltages to be very small indeed, tending to zero

Comment: This 'trick' can be called an "artificially delayed virtual ground" :-)

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I'm not sure calling it something helps anybody. If anything, it's an *advanced* virtual ground, the capacitor handles the input current step *before* the op-amp can. I don't see anything artificial about it either. So, of that four-word phrase you're suggesting, I disagree with all the words that aren't the 'virtual ground' it's based on. Reinforced VG? Augmented VG?. Fast VG? Non-internally-overloading VG? VG with shunt capacitor at the input? All better than your suggestion IMHO. Perhaps you'd cite a textbook or tutorial that calls it that?

Comment: @Neil_UK, Still, the trick is important, not so much the name that occurred to me just now. It is "artificial" in the sense that we have deliberately added this capacitor in order to "soften" the voltage step. I have not come across it in this form in textbooks;  there I have seen reasoning about the influence of the parasitic capacitance of this point. Also that it was very sensitive to disturbances. I have used the virtual ground phenomenon as an indicator of distortions (clipping) of an audio amplifier (when the amp output reaches a supply rail, the virtual ground voltage begins changing).

Answer (score 1):

## Demystifying virtual short

The question is very important to the understanding of negative feedback op-amp circuits; it is a concept that must be intuitively and not formally explained. The most convincing way is to do this through experiments.

### How to see it

There is hardly a better tool than an ohmmeter for this purpose. Since there is no ready-made one in CircuitLab, we can make it by connecting a battery BAT, an ammeter I and a resistor R in series. Note the ground is required by the simulator.

### Real connection

If the two nodes are connected by a true piece of wire, and we connect the probes of our DIY ohmmeter to them, it will read 0 Ω (1 mA) accirding to Ohm's law (I = V/R = 1 V/1 kΩ = 1 mA).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fySG1e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Virtual connection

Now let's raise the voltages of both nodes to 1V and measure the resistance between them again. What is our surprise when we see that the resistance is again 0 Ω. So, conclude we, the two nodes are again connected by a piece of wire. But where is it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgnIXw.png)</sup>

**The explanation:** Between the two nodes, there are only two sources of equal voltage connected in series and opposite direction. Ah... here is the deal - the total voltage across this circuit is 0 V, the same as it was across the piece of wire above! It is as if the two nodes are connected by a sort of *virtual wire* with zero resistance (voltage) made up of two source voltages in series.

### Op-amp virtual connection

**Voltage follower:** Now let's see this phenomenon in real op-amp circuits. In such a circuit (eg a voltage follower), the input voltage Vin is applied to the non-inverting input, and the op-amp produces a copy Vout = Vin of that voltage at the inverting input. So as in the conceptual diagram above, the two voltages are subtracted; the result is 0 V, and the ohmmeter reads 0 Ω.

The catch here is that we can see the inputs of the op-amp and can ignore the feedback... and so we think the short is between the inputs... but it is external. Let's trace the current path to see where it is.

The current I exits the positive ohmmeter probe, enters NODE 1, flows through Vin, then through the positive voltage supply (not shown), enters the op-amp positive supply pin (not shown), exits its output, leaves NODE 2 and enters the negative ohmmeter probe. The total sum of voltages along this path is zero and it behaves as a *zero virtual resistance* conductor that shunts the op-amp differential input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY7rO4.png)</sup>

**Added resistor disturbance:** Let's use this set up to get a better intuitive idea of the op-amp behavior in negative feedback circuits (it resembles human behavior).

Actually the ohmmeter disturbs the op-amp trying to change the zero voltage difference between its inputs by passing its current through the circuit. The op-amp reacts to this intervention and restores the zero value.

Now let's disturb the op-amp even more with another disturbance - including a 1 kΩ resistor Rf between the op-amp output and the inverting input. As you can see, the op-amp doubles its output voltage (Vout = 2 V) to compensate for this disturbance, and again manages to restore the zero difference at its input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ojPg.png)</sup>

So our conclusion is that *the only thing an op-amp cares about is maintaining zero voltage across its inputs, not its output voltage*. This is the job of all negative feedback systems (including us) - to maintain zero. This zero is an indication to them that they have made one thing Y equal to another thing X. That is why I prefer to call this phenomenon by the more meaningful name "active copying".

**Decreased ohmmeter disturbance:** If we do not want to disturb the op-amp with our measurements, we must reduce the current produced by the ohmmeter several times (by increasing the resistor R to 1 MΩ). Now it manages to compensate for the voltage drop across Rf increasing its output voltage only with 1 mV (Vout = 1.001 V)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF3dyJ.png)</sup>

## Applications

Finally, let's see some applications of this powerful *virtual short* idea.

### Nonserious...

Imagine you need to supply some load (a very imperfect voltmeter with 100 Ω internal resistance in the schematic below) with 10 V at some distance but you do not have wires :-) Instead, you have a lot of batteries. Then you can make "virtual wires" using a string of batteries - an even number, with alternating polarity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8apBs.png)</sup>

They will act like true wires.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLOTep.png)</sup>

### Serious...

**Transimpedance amplifier:** We can make the voltage source V1 by passing a current Iin through the resistor Rf (as in the op-amp arrangements above). The op-amp acts as V2 thus destroying V1. This is the idea of the so-called *transimpedance amplifier*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQRfs3.png)</sup>

This entire circuit effectively behaves like a "piece of wire" with zero resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTGQfX.png)</sup>

## Nature of negative feedback

> Can you explain what is the reason for an op-amp in negative feedback to make the terminals have the same voltage?

Let's consider the simplest op-amp circuit with negative feedback - the *op-amp follower*. Here we have applied the input voltage to the non-inverting input and the output voltage of the op-amp to the inverting input.  Thus, we have applied the difference of the two voltages to the differential input of the op-amp (the two voltages are subtracted in series manner, according to KVL) with the purpose to force it to set its output voltage equal to the input voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpcsMp.png)</sup>

> And how does this happen?

To understand how the op-amp does this "magic", we need to imagine the transient process at the first moment after the input voltage sharply changes (voltage step).

[image: STEP 5a]

Because of some internal capacitances (including the frequency compensation capacitance), the op-amp cannot react instantaneously and at this moment its output voltage does not "move". After that, it starts to grow rapidly but the ratio of its output voltage to that between its inputs - Vout/(V+ - V-), is much less than its (open loop) gain. Figuratively speaking, during the transition, the op-amp is not an amplifier but rather an *integrator*.

[image: STEP 5b]

Eventually ***it stops when the ratio becomes equal to the open loop gain***. At this *equilibrium point*, the op-amp becomes an amplifier again.

[image: STEP 5c]

Answer (score 1):

Because, well... at the end of the day, all opamps have only one job in life... try and keep the voltage difference ***between*** their two inputs as close to zero as possible.

If (IN- > IN+) then the output swings negative as we've clearly got too much "positive" input so we need to counter it with some "negative" output.

Whereas, if (IN- < IN+) then the output swings positive because now we've got the opposite problem and have too much "***negative***" input.

If I connect ***one*** of the inputs to ***actual ground*** and stick some resistors between the other and the output. If I apply a ***positive*** voltage to Vin, well the voltage at the "-" terminal will start to ***rise***, right? But remembering that if IN+ < IN- we get a ***negative*** output from the opamp, well now the "-" terminal's voltage starts to go ***down***. But, hold on, we've ***also*** got stuff coming from Vin going the other way... so the two opposing voltage sources duke it out and (ideally) cancel to zero (or whatever voltage the "+" terminal is at)

[image: Basic diagram of an inverting opamp]

It's not that the inputs are ***physically*** shorted (they can measure ***teraohms*** on some devices), but it's because the opamp tries to make it so that it's inputs ***function*** as if they're shorted together (until you overload the poor thing, then all bets are off)

But what happens when the output is shorted to the "-" input?

[image: High-impedance non-inverting buffer]

Well, the opamp still wants to keep the difference between "+" and "-" the same, but now we've gone and stuck a "zero" ohm link in there. There's only ***one*** way for the opamp to keep its inputs matched, right? It now ***has*** to track the input, it has no other choice... it ***must*** try and minimize the difference between "+" and "-" (that's its one job, remember?) and therefore it ***must*** now follow the input signal.

As for ***why*** opamps behave this way, well, because we ***design them specifically*** to be like this. Turns out, it's really useful and allows you to build everything from voltage buffers to calculating logarithms and generating near-perfect sine waves (check out a "wein bridge oscillator", they're pretty neat!)

Comment: "*... all opamps have only one job in life... try and keep the voltage difference between their two inputs as close to zero as possible.*" That's not quite right. If you said, "most op-amp ***circuits*** ..." that might be true. Have a look at an op-amp-based Schmitt trigger or other positive-feedback circuits to see why.

Comment: Interesting way of explaining… but I have some observations. 1) You should clarify why "all opamps have only one job in life..." 2) If (IN- < IN+) then the output swings positive, not negative. 3) "As for why opamps behave this way", I think the main reason is *that we have connected them this way (by a negative feedback)*.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Whoops, yes, you're right about the signs

Comment: @Transistor Given that the opamp is amplifying (in opposition to) the difference between IN+ and IN-, would it not be fair to say that even if the opamp is being used as a schmitt or comparator, it's still trying to correct the difference between its inputs, it's just that the circuit built around it has been configured to exploit that inherent behavior? The opamp's still a difference amplifier with ridiculous gain and it's still ***trying*** to correct itself, it's just that we've just gone and put the steering wheel on backwards...

Comment: @Sam, "*Given that the opamp is amplifying (in opposition to) the difference between IN+ and IN- ...*" But it doesn't! It amplifies **in proportion** to the difference between IN+ and IN-. The comparator I mentioned as an example would usually have **no feedback** and is running open-loop. (Op-amps do not make very good comparators as there can be a long recovery time if the output saturates.) There is nothing inherent in the op-amp's design that makes it try to correct the difference. It is only the configuration of the circuit built around it.

Answer (score 1):

> The equation the model the functionality of the op amp is that
> $$V_{out}=A_0(V_+−V_−)$$

This is correct for dc and steady state. I prefer to write the equation: $$V_{out}=A_{VOL}v_D$$.

Using \$A_{VOL}\$ indicates that it is the open loop gain that multiplies the differential input \$v_D=(V_+−V_−)\$. This is true whether there is negative feedback or not.

> In case of negative feedback the
> $$V_+=V_−$$
> Where does that came from: (that the two terminals in case of negative feedback become virtually connected)?

This as an approximation (some would say an idealization).The two inputs are not virtually connected. For an inverting configuration, \$V_-\$ is called a virtual ground. For a non-inverting configuration, \$V_-\$ is sometimes called a virtual input. But the phrase vitually connected is not a good concept to entertain.

I do not like the use of virtual and try to avoid using it. What it really means is that the voltage on \$V_-\$ tracks the voltage on \$V_+\$. But there is always a small voltage differential between them. Only a small (insignificant?) current passes between them.

Whether open-loop or closed loop (negative feedback), when the output is within its range of operation (ie. not saturated) the voltage between the input pins is **always**: $$v_D=\frac{V_{out}}{A_{VOL}}$$

This equation is valid only if the output is within its range of operation. Open loop operation requires the input to be externally controlled to stay within the range of operation. Negative feedback does that automatically.
As you can see, as \$A_{VOL}\$ becomes large, \$v_D\$ becomes insignificant.

When we say that \$V_+=V_−\$ we mean \$V_+-V_−\$ is insignificant so for now treat it as \$V_+-V_−=0\$

Don't try to map an approximation \$V_+=V_−\$ into reality \$V_{out}=A_{VOL}(V_+−V_−)\$. The approximation is there to make "back of napkin" calculations easier, and not to represent the truth.

Answer (score 0):

A different way of looking at your statement:

> \$V_+ = V_−\$

> Where does that came from: (that the two terminals in case of negative feedback become virtually connected)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs09R0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here \$ V_{node1} = V_{node2} \$ but nobody would say that the two nodes are virtually connected.

Comment: But they are connected... and you can simply check it by an ohmmeter (see my answer).